# Leiningen REPL not autoloading project.core namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces, read-eval-print-loop

I'm new to Clojure so this could very well be an easy question.  I'm having an issue with the REPL while using Leiningen.

Previously, I had created an `app` project while following a tutorial.  When I would launch the REPL using `lein repl` with that project, it would always put me in the project's core namespace automatically.  Even though I was in that namespace, I could still access built-in resources e.g. `(doc build-in-function-name)`, etc.

Now, I've created another non-app project and I seem to have lost this autoloading capability.  I'm now being put into a `user` namespace by default.  Also, when I try to get access to my project's core namespace by doing `(in-ns 'project.core)`, I lose access to build-in functions like `doc`.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: May be you should use "clojure.repl" namespace. I think lein repl autoloads "clojure.repl" namespace in every other namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in-ns` does not load code. It switches to an ns, creating it if needed. It also does not do the default ns setup (eg. referring clojure.core). The proper way to load a namespace from code in the repl is with require `(require 'some.ns)`, which can then be followed by `(in-ns 'some.ns)` if it succeeds.

You can use the `:repl-options {:init-ns some.ns}` option in project.clj to specify the namespace that leiningen should auto-load into your repl. When it's up to me I do not use this option, because it prevents me from having a usable repl if there is any bug that prevents my code from loading.

Comment: `(load "core")` works for me.